# Change DPI on Logitech MX Anywhere 2S

Tags: mouse, display-resolution, logitech, dpi

The Logitech MX Anywhere 2S mouse has support for changing the DPI but only through its software which is unfortunately only available for Windows and Mac.

[Solaar](https://pwr.github.io/Solaar/) has support for the but not for changing the [DPI for this mouse](https://pwr.github.io/Solaar/devices.html). Is there any other way of changing the DPI? I don't have Windows or Mac so unfortunately cannot dual-boot in order to change the DPI settings.

Comment: Related: https://community.logitech.com/s/question/0D55A00007AK4OASA1/mx-anywhere-2s-dpi-setting